# Django - Inserting data into a many to many relationship model with unique constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a models.py:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        SkillCategory, default=None, null=True, blank=True
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And in my views I am basically getting a set of skills which I use to populate the `UserProfile` and `Skills` models after login:

```
@login_required
def UpdateUserSkills(request):
    cleaned_skills = get_skill_list(user=request.user)

    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
        user=request.user
    )

    for s in cleaned_skills:
        user_profile.skill.get_or_create(title=s)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show_user_profile'))
```

My question is - does this method of adding skills respect the unique constraint of the model, and if it does, will it NOT populate those skills for a given user if they already exist? Would it perhaps be better to do something like this:

```
for s in cleaned_skills:
    skill = Skill.objects.get_or_create(title=s)
    user_profile.skill.get_or_create(title=skill)
```

Though this seems as though it will generate double the number of DB queries.

Perhaps there is another, better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
for s in cleaned_skills:
    skill = Skill.objects.get_or_create(title=s)
    user_profile.skill.add(skill)
```

That will only create the skill if a skill with that same title does not already exist. It then adds the skill to the user.

EDIT: you could save a few queries, if you do a `bulk_create`. Something like this:

```
skill_titles = Skill.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)
new_skills = Skill.objects.bulk_create([Skill(title=s) for s in cleaned_skills if s not in skill_titles])
user_profile.skill.add(*new_skills)
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Extra marks for two workable solutions. Django debug toolbar actually reports the queries to be exactly the same number, in the same time. So I will implement the first solution as it is a bit more legible.